# iBatis schemas not working in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xsd, ibatis, ibatis.net

iBatis comes with three schema files that provide intellisense to VS.Net.

According to [the iBatis help docs](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch04s02.html), the location should be this:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\xml
```

or this if you have x64 installed:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\xml
```

They list two other alternatives, but neither of them seem relevant to 2010.

No dice so far.  Is there a different schema folder for 2010?  I'm sure I'm write on top of it.

The [new MyBatis website](http://mybatis.org/dotnet.html) doesn't have any docs that mention it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm an idiot.  I figured it out.  The right location is:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas
```

or this if you have an x64 box:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas
```

VS 2010 has that new nifty Xml Schemas dialogue box built right in.  After I found that, the path was obvious.